# Get access to yaml external file in Thorntail

Tags: snakeyaml, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I want to get access to external YAML file which I specify through command-line argument:

```
java -jar target/app-thorntail.jar -s./test.yaml
```

This file I need to use to get my custom properties tree by SnakeYaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Inject @ConfigurationValue` for your custom properties, and you can `@Inject` a `ConfigView` to read the entire configuration tree. I believe that should be enough for your usecase. This approach will also provide correct values in case multiple configuration files are used.

I'm not sure if you can get access to the file itself, except maybe provide a custom `main` method and parse the command-line arguments yourself.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks, Ladicek!

Comment: Please, read: https://github.com/fraballi/thorntail-microservices-multiple-profiles. There is a section for configuration/stages ways and external files.